# EntityMalformedException at delete product (Drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce, commerce

I recently installed drupal commerce and am using the auction module, ever since i've been unable to delete a product. It always throws the following exception:

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_product.
in entity_extract_ids() (line 7808 of/home/deb72708/domains/bla/includes/common.inc).
```

I've tried almost everything said on the drupal forums , commerce repair included. BUT all the threads concerning this problem seem to be about creating/updating a product and/or are very old

Anybody who has come across this problem recently?

Comment: There are 2 auction modules. Please provide the url of the auction module as also as some more details about the steps before that problem occurs.

Comment: this is the module : https://drupal.org/project/commerce_auction

Scenario :  Manage Products -> delete a product - > errors occurs

Comment: There is already a [related error in module issues](https://drupal.org/node/1778408) that is of status _closed (works as designed)_.